# How to show videos from sdcard in thumbnail view?

Tags: android

How can I get a list of all videos from a folder on the sdcard and display the thumbnails in a list? When I click on a thumbnail, it should then open that video for playback.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

We can't give you whole code. Just suggestion from me that how you can achieve that.
you can use that code to see media in your particular folder.

```
String fileUrl = "/myfolder/";
String MEDIA_PATH = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +       
fileUrl;
```

And here is filter code for searching particular extension.

```
class Mp4Filter implements FilenameFilter {
 public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".mp4"));
  }
}
```

For generating thumbnails in listview go [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/05/display-video-thumbnail-in-listview.html)

For starting video on click, You need to implement onListItemClick. Like that:-

```
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 currentPosition = position;
 playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video Start",
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```